# adding a variable into a function

Tags: php, html, sql

Hello, I have a granit php function but would like to print my own text into it, which is stored inside a variable.

This is how the code looks before I enter the variable:

```
 gradient('FF0000', '0000FF', 'my test goes here');
```

Which works fine, but now I want to put the variable where the text goes like so

```
   gradient('FF0000', '0000FF', '".$profile."');
```

Which just echos out $profile onto the page. I can echo out $profile and it works fine, but I want to add the granit function to it.

What am I doing wrong ??

Comment: What is "the granit function" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

simply:

```
gradient('FF0000', '0000FF', $profile);
```

Or:

```
$color1 = 'FF0000';
$color2 = '0000FF';
$profile = 'my test goes here';

gradient($colour1, $colour2, $profile);
```

Comment: Thanks never thought of that :)

Comment: would this work then gradient($colour1,$colour2,$profile);     ??

Answer (score 0):

```
$profile = 'my test goes here';
gradient('FF0000', '0000FF', $profile);
```

Will work.

Comment: gradient($colour1,$colour2,$profile); if i put colours in side the other 2 colour